# unpacking problems in conditional operator in python

Tags: python-3.x

`a,b = b,a if a<b else a,b`

I wrote this python code to apply my gcd function.
But it didn't worked and cause unpacking problems.
Why it dosen't working?

I try to seek for python refers but not a single one have a certain answer about this. I want to know about details.

Comment: `,` has lower precedence than `if-else`, so `b,a if a<b else a,b` is parsed as `b, (a if a < b else a), b`.